# Removing duplicates from multiple columns using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I am working on a project where I am removing duplicates from 95 columns using VBA. Currently I have 95 lines of code that works, but the macro runs significantly slower since expanding from 40 lines to 95. Perhaps that is just the nature of it, but I am looking to learn more about VBA and see if there is a simpler way of solving this. My current macro looks like this, for 95 separate columns:

```
Range("g230:g324").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=x1No
Range("h230:h324").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=x1No
Range("i230:i324").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=x1No
Range("j230:j324").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=x1No
```

It works, but it's slow. Is there a way to select the entire range of cells and have the macro remove the duplicates in each row? 
I tried a different code on a smaller sample size to test it out and I received the 1004 run-time error.

```
Dim Dupes As Range: Set Dupes = Sheet1.Range("M3:X30")
Dupes.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(95, 12), Header:=xlYes
```

I don't believe it's the definition that is wrong, as if I type `Dupes = 2` it fills the range with the number 2.

What I want my macro to do is to go from this (the "a" in the top row is to work around any errors that come from having empty columns)
[image]

To an end result that looks like this
[image]

Comment: I doubt if even a full array or dictionary would be substantially faster than Excel's native remove duplicates but you could run a loop that would turn your 95 lines of code into 3 or 4 lines. Using With ... End With statements would help re-referencing the same objects.

Comment: See [Switch off properties during macro execution](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5925/switch-off-properties-during-macro-execution#t=201702211945392506537) for other 'make-it-faster' tips.

Comment: Thank you for providing that list, it made a noticeable difference in terms of speed.